# Converting volume to dimensions

Tags: dimensional-analysis, unit-conversion, volume

Not sure if this is better posted in mathematics, but I'd like to know the formula used to convert cubic meters to dimensions (eg: 1m height x 1m width x 1m length).

I understand that you can turn cubic meters into a rectangular cube infinitely, but I want to know how to turn let's say $60m^3$ to dimensions for a cube (equal lengths).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but if I do then the cube root operation should do the trick?

$$height = width = length =\sqrt[3]{volume}$$

e.g.:

$$\sqrt[3]{60m^3}=3.915m$$

Some calculators use: $${60m}^{(1/3)} = 3.915m$$